# AWS CDK Deployment - ordering of resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have an AWS architecture where I am introducing a configuration database that multiple Lambdas will be dependant upon.

The configuration database is populated via CDK: by creating an S3 bucket, uploading data to that S3 bucket, which in turn notifies a Lambda that will populate the Database.

I have other Lambdas dependant upon the database being populated, one such Lambda is on a cron and is initially invoked by the CDK via custom resources - therefore timing is critical.

At the moment ALL of the AWS resources are deployed via a SINGLE stack, which is giving me problems - I'm not sure whether this is a timing issue down to the ordering of resources being deployed.

I was considering splitting out the Configuration Database AWS resources into a NEW Stack which would be played in first before the EXISTING Stack. This would hopefully guarantee the data being available?

I was wondering if anyone has any previous experience in such a solution, and can suggest what works best ?

Comment: My understanding of the AWS-CDK, mainly to generating Cloudformation script from "programming". So for your case where you want to make sure the lambda execution is after the Cloudformation is deployed, this may be handled after you call the "cdk deploy", invoke the lambda manually from the CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CloudFormation the provisioning of resources happens in parallel unless a resource has dependencies.

You can try to use [dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#dependencies), but being that you're trying to work in the invocation of the Lambdas into the timing of your CloudFormation stack deployment (which probably is an anti-pattern) you'll need to implement a [WaitCondition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudformation.CfnWaitCondition.html).

Moving resources into a separate Stack likely will just make your deployments more complex.